# Python generators: understanding the order of execution

Tags: python, generator

```
 21 def power(values):
 22     print "power", values
 23     for value in values:
 24         print 'powering %s' % value
 25         yield value
 26
 27 def adder(values):
 28     print "adder", values
 29     for value in values:
 30         print 'adding to %s' % value
 31         if value % 2 ==0:
 32             yield value + 3
 33         else:
 34             yield value + 2
 35
 36 elements = [1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 19]
 37 res = adder(power(elements))
 38 print res.next()
 39 print res.next()
 40 print res.next()
 41 print res.next()
```

OUTPUT:

```
adder <generator object power at 0x7fb6b9ee7910>          <--- is this the stdout flush matter?
power [1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 19]
powering 1
adding to 1
3
powering 4
adding to 4
7
powering 7
adding to 7
9
powering 9
adding to 9
11
```

I am trying to understand the above code.
1) why did adder  got printed before power [1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 19]?

2) adder is not iterating through elements but iterating through power generator, correct?

3) confirm my thought on (1). so adder gets called first then in `for value in values` for adder, it's consulting power generator and hence, powering print line gets triggered and then adder print line gets triggered?

4) If so, why doesnt the print statement `power [1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 19]` gets called along with the `powering <$>` print statement every time?

Comment: Make sure you understand the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `power` has a `yield` return, which makes it a `generator`. The code in the function itself is only execute when `next()` is called on it.
2. correct. `adder` relies on the generator, and has no information on the data being iterated. (such as the size)
3. correct again
4. `yield` is a particular instruction. It does not return from the generator function (`power`). Instead, it provides one value, and **suspend** its execution until the next call to `next()`. At this point, the execution is resumed at the same point, which is inside the loop.

### Edit

Illustration of the `yield` stopping point:

```
def gene():
    print 'first!'
    yield 1
    print 'second!'
    yield 2

g = gene()
g.next()
# first!
# 1
g.next()
# second!
# 2
```

As you can see, the generator is interrupted exactly after the `yield` instruction, ready to execute the next one

Comment: at 4 repsonse, ohhh that makes sense. so it doesnt go back to the beginning each time but rather knows where it stopped previously.

Comment: then lets say there was a code after yield. Where is that "stopping point"? Does it end with the yield or ends after that specific iteration of the for loop?

Comment: the yield. I'll edit my answer to add a simple example

Answer (score 4):

Generator functions don't begin execution until the first call to `__next__` on the generator.  For example:

```
>>> def gen():
...     print 'starting execution'
...     for i in range(10): yield i
...
>>> itr = gen()
>>> next(itr)
starting execution
0
```

So to answer you first question, "why did adder got printed before power", when you do `adder(power(elements))` the generator `power(elements)` is created first, but the execution of that generator will not begin until the first iteration of `for value in values` within `adder()`.

Answer (score 3):

Code inside a generator is not run until next is called:

```
def gen():
    print "called"
    yield 3.14

g = gen()  # nothing is printed
g.next()  # print "called" and return 3.14
```

*The for loop is doing the job of calling next here, in your code this is happening after the adder is printed:*

```
g = gen()

print 'adder'  # prints adder

for i in g: # prints called (as inside generator, *before* yields)
    print i  # prints 3.14
```

Comment: so my question (4) is that, since adder is also a generator, calling next would affect it. why isnt "print power", values" in power() gets called each time with next?

Comment: @ealeon a generator is like a function with a pause button, when it yields it remembers where it was, on the next next it continues where it left off.